# Nginx with SSL connection error

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, seo, http2

I'm trying to migrate a site from HTTP to HTTPS, however, my nginx (version: 1.10.3) config seems not to be working.

The following behavior is desired:

- `http://www.example.com/path/to/content` should redirect to `https://example.com/path/to/content`
- `http://example.com/path/to/content` should redirect to `https://example.com/path/to/content`
- `https://www.example.com/path/to/content` should redirect to `https://example.com/path/to/content`

With my current config browsers wont connect to the site using HTTPS:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    # redirects both www and non-www to https
    rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;

    # redirects non-www to www
    rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    charset utf-8;

    # rest of my config
}
```

- What do I have to change to achieve the above mentioned behavior?
- Is it possible to accept (and later redirect) HTTP requests in a first step in order to keep the page "live" and let me test it?
- My site has very good SEO rankings (indexed as "http://www.example.com"), so properly redirecting is a must.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites

Comment: Did you try to include the ssl files in both server blocks that describe a ssl connection?

Comment: No, I didn't. Good catch, will try that later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration makes what you ask:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    # redirects both www and non-www to https
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.example.com;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    # redirects www to non-www
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    charset utf-8;

    # rest of my config
}
```

I changed `rewrite` to `return`, since that is a bit more efficient.
With `return` one has to use `$request_uri` to get the request path and arguments into the redirect URL.

Then I changed the `server_name example.com;` with `listen 443;` block to serve the actual contents of the site, and `server_name www.example.com;` with `listen 443;` to make redirect.

Comment: Awesome, will try that! Could you explain the difference between the second and the fourth server block? Why is the fourth server block needed? The only difference I see is the `permanent` keyword.

Comment: That was a mistake from my part, I was partly copy-pasting your question to form my answer and mistakingly copy-pasted one part too much. I fixed the answer now.

Comment: Kiitos, Tero :)

Comment: Writing "listen 443 ssl http2" instead of just "listen 443" solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try by using below method and update rest ssl info:

```
server {  
       listen 80;  
       listen [::]:80;  
       server_name www.example.com example.com;
       return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;  
}
```

And For ssl provide the ssl key path:

```
server {  
 listen   443 ssl;
 ssl on;  
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;  
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;  
  ssl_certificate      /path of certificate;  
 ssl_certificate_key  /path of server.key;
}
```

Comment: So, basically you're suggesting to replace `rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1 permanent;` with `return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;` in the first server block? All SSL related config is in `ssl-example.com.conf` and `ssl-params.conf` which are then included.

Comment: yes, where return 301 is redirecting http request into https.Also can use:  
 return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

Comment: `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri` introduces one useless 301 redirect when you access `http://example.com`. First redirect will be to `https://example.com`, and then to `https://www.example.com`. You don't want that.